# Laravel Queue Eloquent Issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, queue, jobs

I'm currently using https://github.com/Parziphal/parse to be able to use Parse database in an Eloquent manner. The issue I'm facing is that inside the `handle()` function, I am trying to update a certain value. However the job keeps repeating and does not complete. It seems to me like any calls to the database inside the `handle()` function will cause this problem.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
class SendQueuedSMS extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    public $receipt = null;

    public function __construct(Receipt $receipt ) {
        $this->receipt = $receipt ;
        $this->sendSlack("Constructor ");

    }

    public function handle() {
        // Send SMS
        $this->sendSlack("Status: " . $this->receipt->getObjectId());
        $this->receipt->set("smsStatus", "true");
        $this->receipt->save(); // can't get pass here
        return;
    }

    public function failed(Exception $exception) {
        $this->sendSlack($exception->getMessage());
    }
```

}

I cleared my logs and tested again and found out that it output this error.

```
[2017-02-01 20:34:24] local.ERROR: Exception: You must call Parse::initialize() before making any requests. in /var/www/html/housetrac.com/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:415
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/housetrac.com/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseClient.php(319): Parse\ParseClient::assertParseInitialized()
#1 /var/www/html/housetrac.com/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php(376): Parse\ParseClient::_request('GET', 'classes/Receipt...', NULL, NULL, false)
#2 /var/www/html/housetrac.com/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php(306): Parse\ParseQuery->find(false)
#3 /var/www/html/housetrac.com/app/Http/Controllers/Traits/ParseHelper.php(215): Parse\ParseQuery->first()
```

Seems like the ParseClient is not initialized as it was in the bootstrap.

## FIXED - Added Initialization Code

So I included the initialization codes for `ParseSDK` and it worked.

```
    ParseClient::initialize('MYAPP', '', MYTOKEN');
    ParseClient::setServerURL('http://127.0.0.1:4040', 'parse');
```

However, I'm pretty sure it's not good to keep initializing the ParseClient every single time. Has anyone encountered this before and is there any better way to handle this?